# Error message within a loop?

Tags: c

This is the question.
**Write a program that asks the user to enter a number between 1 - 5. Your program should display all the numbers between 1 - 20 that are evenly divisible by this number. You will need to use a loop.**

I want to input an error message when the user enters a number outside the range, but i just cannot figure out how to do it, or where to put it.
Here is my code so far, which will allow the user to enter any number.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int num = 0;
    int i = 0;

    printf("Please enter a number from 1 to 5\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    for(i>=1; i<=20; i++)
        {
            if(i %num == 0)
            {
                printf("%d",i);
            } //end if

        }//end loop

}//end main()
```

Comment: C or C++? Which standard (C89, C99, C11, C++98, C++11)? Which compiler, how do you compile? which operating system? Enable all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). **Use the debugger** (`gdb`). Read about [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) - and about every function you are using. You should use the result of `scanf` and preferably end with `\n` every `printf` format string. **Edit your question** to improve it!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add one extra condition to check whether the given value fall into the range or not.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num = 0;
    int i ; // There is no need to intialize variable.
    printf("Please enter a number from 1 to 5\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    if( num >=1 && num <= 5)
    {
        for(i=1; i<=20; i++)
        {
            if(i %num == 0)
            {
                printf("%d",i);
            } //end if
         } // end for
    } //end if
    else
    {
        printf("Error Message\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
if (num > 5 || num < 1)
{
    cout << "Error Message!";
}
```

And remember to put this into the loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
    while(1) // infinite loop
     {
              if(scanf("%d",&num)==0)// if scanning an integer failed
              {
                    printf("Invalid input. Try again:");
                    scanf("%*s"); //remove the invalid input
                    continue; //loop again
              }
              if(num>0 && num<6)//if num is in range of 1 and 5
                    break; // break out of loop
              else
                    printf("invalid integer. Try again:");
     }
```

Replace your `scanf` with the above code.

Also,you need `i=1` instead of `i>=1` in your `for` loop as you want to assign `i` to 1

Comment: You have something right there. Indenting the code and removing the continue statement might help.

Comment: @2501 , Why remove the `continue`?